# FilePond is not defined only in npm run dev

Tags: laravel, vite, filepond

I use laravel 9 with vite and
I want run `npm run build` and show me *FilePond is not defined* only filepond work with
`npm run dev`
How i can fix ?

this is my vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import  FilePond from "./resources/assets/filepond/js/filepond.js";
import   "./resources/assets/filepond/css/filepond.css";
import   "./resources/assets/filepond/css/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css";
import   "./resources/assets/filepond/js/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/assets/filepond/js/filepond.js',
                'resources/assets/filepond/css/filepond.css',
                'resources/assets/filepond/css/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css',
                'resources/assets/filepond/js/filepond-plugin-image-preview.js',               
                     'public/theme/dist/assets/js/widgets.bundle.js',                    'public/theme/dist/assets/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js',
                'public/theme/dist/assets/css/style.bundle.css',
                'public/theme/dist/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js',
                'public/theme/dist/assets/css/style.bundle.rtl.css',
                'public/theme/dist/assets/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js'                 
                ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

i use

> ```
> php artisan route:clear 
> php artisan cache:clear 
> php artisan config:clear
> php artisan config:cache
> ```

this part of my view

```
<head>
 @vite('resources/assets/filepond/css/filepond.css') 

        <title>Laravel</title>
@vite('resources/assets/filepond/js/filepond.js')
```

Comment: Please tell me which tutorial are you trying to make and run?

Comment: I finished my project, I always ran npm run dev to be able to visualize the changes in the front end and I realized that the filepond function did not work without run npm run dev , and I want to go to the deployment stage